# Firestore - Logical collection schema for setting data per user?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a structure for an angular app I'm building whereby each user has their own dataset that is used for their login, so each should have their own 'Expenses', 'Contacts', 'Invoices' collections.

From what I understand, there should therefore be documents with id's of the user's uid value that are accessed through queries of the main collection in which the user's data is searched-for. So inside the top-level 'Contacts' collection in the firestore console, there should be documents labelled with each user's uid, which then contain their own arrays of contacts available to them.

Demonstration below:

[image: Demonstration of proposed firestore database schema/structure]

Does this look like the correct approach to implement data per user?

Comment: Did you find a good answer for this? I have the same question about how to handling this situation

Answer (score 10):

There is no singular "correct" approach for data modeling. It all depends on the use-cases of our app.

One option would be to have a top-level `users` collection with a document for each user, and then per user have `contacts`, `expenses` and `invoices` collections.

But that's just one way and as said, it all depends on your use-cases. For example with the model above, you can't query across the invoices for all users. And if you want to have an invoice shared between two users, you'll need to add it to the `/users/$uid/invoices` collection of each user. If that doesn't meet your app's use-cases, then you could consider storing the invoices in a top-level `/invoices` collection, and adding references to them from each user.

There are too many variations to fine a one-size-fits-all solution, which is why you won't find standard data models without accompanying standard apps. The two always go hand in hand.

To learn more I recommend reading this article about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Can you please add some more info to your answer? specially about how to deal with the case proposed in the screenshot, it was not so clear for me